# R - Using APPLY on a specific column in a matrix

Tags: r, regex, matrix, apply

I have a matrix. I'll make a simple example below.

```
    ID_Num    Name    text
1   123       Ari\n     "I\nlove"
2   456       Zona\r    "Arizona\r\Iced\n"
3   789       Tea     "tea!!\n\r"
```

I want to remove the \n and \r ONLY from the text column for whatever reason.

How do I do this with apply?

Saying....

```
matrix = apply( matrix, 1, function(x) gsub("[\r\n\]", "", x["text"])
```

Doesn't seem to give me the desired result, returning a null matrix.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use `apply` as you are working simply with a column `df$text` (assuming that `df` is your data frame). To modify it you may use

```
df$text <- gsub("[\\r\\n]", "", df$text)
```